# while Extracting the features & storing them in a list error is occurring

Tags: python, machine-learning, dataset, urllib, phishing

gaierror                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\urllib\request.py:1348, in AbstractHTTPHandler.do_open(self, http_class, req, **http_conn_args)
1347 try:
-> 1348     h.request(req.get_method(), req.selector, req.data, headers,
1349               encode_chunked=req.has_header('Transfer-encoding'))
1350 except OSError as err: # timeout error

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py:1282, in HTTPConnection.request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
1281 """Send a complete request to the server."""
-> 1282 self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py:1328, in HTTPConnection._send_request(self, method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
1327     body = _encode(body, 'body')
-> 1328 self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py:1277, in HTTPConnection.endheaders(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
1276     raise CannotSendHeader()
-> 1277 self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)

File C:\ProgramData\anaconda3\lib\http\client.py:1037, in HTTPConnection._send_output(self, message_body, encode_chunked)
1036 del self._buffer[:]
-> 1037 self.send(msg)
1039 if message_body is not None:
1040
1041     # create a consistent interface to message_body